# Invalid Podfile file specifying multiple post_install hooks is unsupported

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I'm using cocoapods 1.1.1 and in my podfile I have more than one post_install hooks. And I'm getting this error :

```
[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: [!] Specifying multiple `post_install` hooks is unsupported..
-------------------------------------------
 #
 >  post_install do |installer|
 #      installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
```

Did anyone face the same problem before? And Yes! I have 1 post_install in my 1 target and another in global scope. I could move in one, but why?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Solution 2023

When I removed my code from my main target and moved in global scope's post_install block it's works like charm.

For some reason if you add multiple post_install (global and 1 target for instance) move them in same global block and add if-else statements for managing targets.

Answer (score 4):

I temporarily solved this conflict. Put the code in your Podfile.

```rb
def multiple_post_install(flutter_application_path)
  #read podhelper from flutter_application_path
  flutter_podhelper = File.read(File.join(flutter_application_path, '.ios', 'Flutter', 'podhelper.rb'))

  #find the post_install end location by hardcoding
  post_install_string = 'post_install do |installer|'
  location = flutter_podhelper.index(post_install_string)
  location += post_install_string.length

  #declare your own hook func
  update_configs_func = %q[
  update_configs(installer)]

  #insert the func you declare
  flutter_podhelper.insert(location, update_configs_func)
  return flutter_podhelper
end

flutter_application_path = 'path/to/my_flutter/'
flutter_podhelper = multiple_post_install(flutter_application_path)
eval(flutter_podhelper, binding)

def update_configs(installer)
  #put your own custom code
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Move all of them to one place like this, it worked for me.

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
     if config.build_settings['WRAPPER_EXTENSION'] == 'bundle'
     config.build_settings['DEVELOPMENT_TEAM'] = 'S09DP9UN6F'
   end
  end
 end
end
```

after

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      if config.build_settings['WRAPPER_EXTENSION'] == 'bundle'
        config.build_settings['DEVELOPMENT_TEAM'] = 'S09DP9UN6F'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def main_pods
pod 'CocoaLumberjack', '2.0.0'
pod 'MBProgressHUD', '0.9.1'

post_install do |installer_representation|
    installer_representation.pods_project.targets.each do |target|

        if target.name == 'Pods-AFNetworking'
            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= ['$(inherited)']
                config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] << '_AFNETWORKING_ALLOW_INVALID_SSL_CERTIFICATES_=1'
            end
        end

    end
end
```

end

Comment: Please try to remove post_install block. And try again. And share warnings after "pod install"

Comment: Ok now (as expected) "pod install" works correctly, but compiler now show me some warnings:
`ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-TargetName/Pods-TargetName.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation

Comment: I'm glad. Now check your warnings in Xcode, if Xcode has some update for settings, let it update your settings

Comment: Yep.. now it works correctly and for your info, moving "post_install" out of main block, solved all the problems with GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS macro in different target. Well done!

Answer (score 3):

I had the Similar Issue , Its Because of the Location Permission Which I added in POD file . then I comment Out this Portion and it works .

```
# post_install do |installer|
#   installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
#     flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
#   end
# end
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)

    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= [
        '$(inherited)',

        ## Add this line
         'PERMISSION_LOCATION=1'
      ]
    end
  end
end
```

---

Full Code : POD file

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

# post_install do |installer|
#   installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
#     flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
#   end
# end
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)

    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= [
        '$(inherited)',

        ## Add this line
         'PERMISSION_LOCATION=1'
      ]
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

use `abstract_target`

Link [click here](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html)

Comment: Please, read the post carefully. This no about abstract_target.